# Changing css dynamically without reloading page in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-style

I have a side navigation bar, wherein there is progress bar in each nav.
This is modular structure-

```
MainFile
   -Children1
       -children1.html
       -children1.component.ts
  -Children2
       -children2.html
       -children2.component.ts
  -Children3
       -children3.html
       -children3.component.ts
  -ProgressIndicator
       -progressIndicator.html
       -progressIndicator.component.ts
  -main.html
  -main.component.ts
```

Inside progressIndicator.html, I have this code,

```
 <div class="progress">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'width':getProgress()}" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-
       valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
       <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
   </div>
```

And my progressIndicator.component.ts

```
currentPage = '';
progressBar = '';
//getting current route name using 'this.route.url' and updating 'currentPage' property in 
constructor.
getProgress(){
   if(currentPage  === 'children1'){
         return progressBar = '25%';
     }
   if(currentPage  === 'children2'){
        return progressBar = '50%';
    }
}
```

I am successfully getting the current page, as 'children1.html' or 'children2.html', based on the current page I want to change the width of div with class 'progress-bar', I used

```
[ngStyle]="{width:getProgress()}"
```

but it takes effect ONLY if page reloads, which angular2 being SPA doesn't happen.
Do help me in finding a better way that when I move from 'children1' to 'children2', the 'getProgress()' takes effect and changes the style.

Answer (score 2):

You should return the whole style object from a method:

*Component*

```
getStyle():any{
    return { width: getProgress() };
}
```

*Template:*

```
[ngStyle]="getStyle()";
```

This way, the whole `getStyle` method will be called upon change detection, which should update your style even if you don't reload (because, as you said, you should never have to reload).

Comment: Its still only changing on reload. :(

Answer (score 2):

Return the full key:value pair in your call. Also bring the assigning of currentPage into your function.

HTML

```
[ngStyle] = "getProgress()"
```

TS

```
getProgress(){
   let currentPage = this.router.url;
   let progressBar;
   if(currentPage  === 'children1'){
         progressBar = {'width' : '25%'};
     }
   if(currentPage  === 'children2'){
         progressBar = {'width' : '50%'};
    }
   return progressBar
}
```

[Here](http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-ngstyle-and-style-binding-example) is a good write up on ngStyle use.

Comment: Its still only changing on reload. :(

Comment: @MichaelPhilips. The answer has been updated. Does this correct this issue?

Comment: No, it does only on reload of the page :(

Comment: @MichaelPhilips Do you have a plunkr of your code? If not, I might try to throw something together and test it later. Just don't have time to build it out now.